# Are these 2 Promise writings equivalent?

Tags: javascript, promise

From a tutorial book I  the following code

```
  createShoppingList: (store, shoppinglist) => {
    return api.addNewShoppingList(shoppinglist).then(() => {
      store.dispatch('populateShoppingLists')
    }, () => {
      store.commit(types.ADD_SHOPPING_LIST, shoppinglist)
    })
  }
```

notice the comma after the .then() block

Is it equivalent to a chained .then() ?

```
  createShoppingList: (store, shoppinglist) => {
    return api.addNewShoppingList(shoppinglist)
    .then(() => {
      store.dispatch('populateShoppingLists')
    })
    .then(() => {
      store.commit(types.ADD_SHOPPING_LIST, shoppinglist)
    })
  }
```

or is it only a block inside the .then() ? 
like :

```
return api.addNewShoppingList(shoppinglist)
.then(
() => { store.dispatch('populateShoppingLists')}, 
() => { store.commit(types.ADD_SHOPPING_LIST, shoppinglist) }
)
```

thanks for feedback

Comment: No, the comma isn't AFTER .then() ... it's within it ... the second callback function to .then is what is called on rejection

Comment: ok thanks... so it seems there is a bug in thi code as BOTH store.commit and store.dispatch should be performed when the apI.addNewShoppingList is resolved ...  in this oredr . commit then dispatch..)

Comment: perhaps, who knows, without full context

Comment: yes,  but in the book context,  qfter adding the shoppingList ( which save it to the server: ShoppingListsResource.save(data) ) then it must be committed into the local store then  re-display the new list by executing the action 'populateShoppingLists' with a dispatch...

Comment: The third snippet is exactly the same as the first, just with a few different linebreaks. Yes, it's obviously different from the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

```
.then(resolved, rejected)
```

is not equal to

```
.then(resolve)
.then(rejected)// :/
```

its rather similar to:

```
.then(resolved)    
.catch(rejected)
```

(Theres still the difference that a rejection inside of then will be catched now, while the upper version is uncatched)

Comment: nope, it's more like `.catch(rejected).then(resolved)`, but not entirely. You'll notice the difference if your `resolved()` method throws another Error; `rejected` won't catch it here.

Comment: @thomas no, that will always enter the then... :/

Comment: But if the `then()` throws an Error, the `catch()` will catch it, and you get a resolved Promise. While with `.then(a,b)` an Error in `a()` won't be catched and get a rejected Promise. IMO `.catch(b).then(a)` is closer to `.then(a,b)` but it still ain't the same thing, as here you will inject the value returned vby the `catch()` block into the `then()`. Ultimately `then(a,b)` is comparable to a condition, as to only one side will be executed, while either with `.catch(b).then(a)` or with `.then(a).catch(b)` both sides can be executed. Check out the snippet in my answer.

Comment: @Jonasw [It's superficially "similar" at best](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572).

Comment: @bergi i know. Thats why *Theres still the difference that a rejection inside of then will be catched now, while the upper version is uncatched*

Comment: @thomas whats your point? I know that. And *IMO* is a good reason to add your own answer which you did, but i doesnt justify the *nope*

Answer (score 0):

No,

```
.then(resolved, rejected)
```

is more like

```
.catch(rejected)
.then(resolved)
```

but not entirely, as with `.then(resolved, rejected)` the result of this function is forwarded to the following Promise, and never to each other.

```js
var resolved = value => `resolve(${value})`;
var rejected = err => `catched(${err})`;
var throwing = () => { throw "thrown Error" };

Promise.resolve(42)
  .then(resolved, rejected)
  .then(v => console.log("then(a,b) => ", v));
  
Promise.reject(42)
  .catch(rejected)
  .then(resolved)
  .then(v => console.log("catch(b).then(a) => ", v));
  
//and that's why .then(a,b) ain't like .then(a).catch(b)
Promise.resolve(42)
  .then(throwing, rejected)  
  .then(v => console.log("then(throw,b) => ", v))
  .catch(err => console.log("then(throw,b) => ", err));


Promise.resolve(42)
  .then(throwing)
  .catch(rejected)  
  .then(v => console.log("then(throw).catch(b) => ", v))
  .catch(err => console.log("then(throw).catch(b) => ", err));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```